# How can I remove dollar signs '$' from a list in Python?

Tags: python, strip

```
sales = ['$1.21', '$2.29', '$14.52', '$6.13', '$24.36', '$33.85', '$1.92']

print(sales.strip('$'))
```

basically any scenario where you are given values with the $ sign and you need them gone, what is the best way to get rid of the dollar sign in python?

Comment: `sales = ['$1.21', '$2.29', '$14.52', '$6.13', '$24.36', '$33.85', '$1.92'] 
print([s.lstrip("$") for s in sales])`
that works! Thanks to RoadRunner!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strip from the left with `str.lstrip()`:

```
>>> sales = ['$1.21', '$2.29', '$14.52', '$6.13', '$24.36', '$33.85', '$1.92']
>>> [s.lstrip("$") for s in sales]
['1.21', '2.29', '14.52', '6.13', '24.36', '33.85', '1.92']
```

Comment: ``sales = ['$1.21', '$2.29', '$14.52', '$6.13', '$24.36', '$33.85', '$1.92']
print([s.lstrip("$") for s in sales])
``
it works! Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

You can strip them:

```
list(map(lambda x: x.strip('$'), sales))
```

Answer (score 1):

I will give an example of split by '$'

```
sales = ['$1.21', '$2.29', '$14.52', '$6.13', '$24.36', '$33.85', '$1.92']
[s.split('$')[1] for s in sales]
['1.21', '2.29', '14.52', '6.13', '24.36', '33.85', '1.92']
```

Answer (score 0):

Since $ sign will always be at 1st position, a simple list comprehension should be enough.

```
sales = ['$1.21', '$2.29', '$14.52', '$6.13', '$24.36', '$33.85', '$1.92']

print(s[1:] for s in sales)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple method

```
sales = [sales[i].strip('$') for i in range(len(sales))]
```

This outputs

```
['1.21', '2.29', '14.52', '6.13', '24.36', '33.85', '1.92']
```